# edit and save the values of a dropdown list dynamically

Tags: jquery, django

I'm rendering a django formfield as ModelChoiceField and populating it with a queryset. BUT,except from the default values of the queryset I want a user to be able to select one from them, edit it(e.g add some more words to it) and the new edited value to be saved in the db. How is that possible? Until now I only managed to do a dropdown list and an alternative combobox but none of them achieves the described functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on default with Django. I would suggest to render a dropdown menu manually in the template, based on values from the database, then use a jQuery plugin like this one:

http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/

Comment: Here is another one: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Editable-Select-Box-editable-select.html